# Does [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:owner: options:] cause memory leaks when used to load custom table cells?

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, custom-controls

Currently I am creating custom table view cells for iPhone using [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:owner:option:] to load the nib. When I profile my app, a memory leak is produced every time I open the view using these custom table cells. The leaks instruments points me to the [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:owner:option:] line. Here is my code:

```
static NSString *challengeCellIdentifier = @"challengeListTableCell";

//NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
ChallengeListTableCell *cell = (ChallengeListTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:challengeCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                loadNibNamed:@"ChallengeListTableCell" 
                                owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ChallengeListTableCell class]]){
            cell = (ChallengeListTableCell *) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Configure the cell...
if(indexPath.row == 0){     // top
    [cell.backgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topMenuBar.png"]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topMenuBarOn.png"]];
}else if(indexPath.row == [challenges count]-1){    //bottom
    [cell.backgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomMenuBar.png"]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomMenuBarOn.png"]];
}else{                              //middle
    [cell.backgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"middleMenuBar.png"]];
    [cell.selectedBackgroundImg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"middleMenuBarOn.png"]];
}


if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) { //ipad
    [cell.title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:40.0f]];
}else{  //iphone
    [cell.title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans-500" size:20.0f]];
}

Challenge * challenge = [challenges objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.title setText:challenge.title];
if([challenge.completed boolValue]){
    [cell.checkImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkComplete.png"]];
} else {
    [cell.checkImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkNotComplete.png"]];
}

return cell;
```

Documentation states that the array returned from loadNibNamed:owner:options: is an autoreleased object, so I don't understand why this causes a leak. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Edited: autoreleasepool was actually commented out in code, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't releasing the autorelease pool you alloc.

Comment: autoreleasepool was actually commented out in code, my apologies. I updated the code in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like poor design...

If the table view cannot recycle a cell, you are loading a NIB...
This is wrong, because the NIB may be loaded, even if the cell can't be recycled.

Then, you assume your `for` loop will get a valid instance. No error checking. Bad...

Finally, you allocate an autorelease pool (don't know why in such a case). You just forgot to release it.

Comment: Loading the custom nib this way is from Apple's own examples for custom dynamic table cells, and should return autoreleased objects. I will add error checking to the loop, thank you for that. And the autoreleasepool was a comment in my code, I updated my post.